# Q: Why Long Short term Memory(LSTM) is called as a Long and Short both type of Memory?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Can any one tell me why LSTM is called as Long and Short both type of memory?
I know in LSTM, they stored the some amount of data of their previous state.
But if it is stored as short time,then why it is called as a Long Term memory, and if it is stored data as a Long Time then why it is called as Short Term memory. 
It's Confusing !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Long Short-Term Memory means storing *Short-Term* data over *Long* periods of time.

Think of for example a piece of text. "Barnie is a big red dog, with little ears and a long black tail. He is 12 years old". If your task was to figure out what "He" refers to in the second sentence, you would send this data into an LSTM network, and it would analyze each word individually. The calculations for a single word is the *Short-Term Memory*. However the calculations of each word (the hidden state), like you say, is passed on and included when analyzing the next word. LSTM networks improve on standard RNNs by being able to store this data for many states, therefore storing the Short-Term data (calculations of individual word) over *Long* periods of time (passing the hidden states to the next word).

Probably a normal RNN could handle the above example, but if you instead input a text of 100 words, a normal RNN would not be able to store all the data, leading to vanishing or exploding gradient. So RNNs are able to store Short-Term data, just like LSTMs, it is just LSTMs can do it over a *longer* period (usually of time).

Answer (score 0):

A generic RNN is capable of learning *short term* dependencies.

An LSTM is a particular type of RNN with a mechanism to avoid the vanishing gradient problem and learn *long term* dependencies. It is still capable of learning short term dependencies, hence the name "Long-Short Term Memory".

Comment: still not understand. can you explain this with example?

Comment: It is just nomenclature so there is no point in making an example. The authors of LSTM came up with a name that explains their architecture is capable of capturing both long and short term dependencies in the data. This is where the name "Long Short Term Memory" come from. If you want to understand how LSTM works that's another story and you should ask a specific question about that.